# Confusion with series, list and unique elements

Tags: python, list, pandas, typeerror, series

I would like to ask some help cause I can't understand a TypeError in a python program.
This piece of code:

```
users2 = np.random.choice(users,5000).tolist()
print len(users2)
print users2[0:20]

for user in users2:
   tags.append(user_counters["tags"].loc[user])

print type(tags)
print set(tags)
```

The type of tags is list. But when I apply set() method to take the unique elements of "tags" list, the following error appears:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Ok, I understand what it means but I can't understand what thing is type of "Series".

On the other hand, if use :

```
print tags.unique()
```

another error makes its appearance:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

*Note*: users_counters is type of **dataframe** and **users** type of **list** with its elements from users_counters.

So why does TypeError mistake happen since *tag* is list *and set()* is for lists?

Thank you in adnvance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `tags` is a list of `pandas.Series` objects. When you build your list from `loc`-based selection from the data-frame:

```
for user in users2:
   tags.append(user_counters["tags"].loc[user])
```

You'll get a `Series`. Then you try to make a set out of a list of series, but you can't because series aren't hashable.

> So why does TypeError mistake happen since tag is list and set() is
>   for lists?

Huh? `set` accepts any iterable, and the elements of that iterable are used to construct the resulting `set`. Your iterable is a `list`, and the elements are `pandas.Series` objects. That is the problem.

I suspect you have a data-frame indexed by a series of strings representing users...

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'tag':[1,2,3, 4], 'c':[1.4,3.9, 2.8, 6.9]}, index=['ted','sara','anne', 'ted'])
>>> df
        c  tag
ted   1.4    1
sara  3.9    2
anne  2.8    3
ted   6.9    4
>>>
```

When you do your selection, since your user-index has non-unique data elements, when you do the following selection, you'll get a `Series`:

```
>>> df['tag'].loc['ted']
user
ted    1
ted    4
Name: a, dtype: int64
>>> type(df['a'].loc['ted'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```